# React input slider Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating an input slider with React Hooks that displays the number the slider is at next to it. I am running into an issue where the slider will not track backwards and is extremely slow to move in any direction. Literally clicking and dragging across the entire screen results in the slider moving 5 units. I'm not sure why this is happening, I'm not getting any errors, but I am extremely new to React, especially with hooks. My relevant code is below, thanks for any help or advice!

JS(Babel):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyledSlider } from "./style";

const Slider = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(120.5);

  return (
    <div className="slider-box">
      <div>
        <label className="slider-label">{value}c</label>
        <p className="slider-title">Scale</p>
      </div>
      <StyledSlider
        list="tickmarks"
        max={1200}
        onChange={() => setValue(value + 1)}
        step={0.01}
        type="range"
        value={value}
      />
      <div> 
        <p className="slider-scale">1200 x 1200</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: See if using `setValue(val => val + 1)` helps.

Answer (score 0):

So, the `onChange={() => setValue(value + 1)}` was unnecessary. Changing it to this fixed the issue:

```
const Slider = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(120.5);

  const onUpdate = (e) => {
     setValue(e.target.value);
  }  

  return (
    <div className="slider-box">
      <div>
        <label className="slider-label">{value}c</label>
        <p className="slider-title">Scale</p>
      </div>
      <StyledSlider
        list="tickmarks"
        max={1200}
        onChange={onUpdate}
        step={0.01}
        type="range"
        value={value}
      />
      <div> 
        <p className="slider-scale">1200 x 1200</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```